# Exchange data between "Virtualbox guest OS COM port" and "Windows host pipe"

Tags: c++, serial-port, pipe, virtualbox

Assume you map Virtualbox guest OS COM port to Windows host pipe (`\\.\pipe\*`) and Virtualbox is server side of pipe.

It is possible to read/write Windows host pipe from client side (from Windows program) by `<stdio>`, i.e. access the pipe (and the guest COM port) as regular stream (via `FILE`, `fopen`, `fgetc`, `fputc`, etc).

1.
The client side pipe behaviour details can depend on conventions offered by Virtualbox server side pipe implementation.

If you are not sure about the server side pipe considerations, you can find unexpected troubles while transfer data, among them:

- client side pipe terminates to receive rx data (windows program begin to read `0x00`);

  ```
  //the following code will not help to 'read after write'
  int
      //begin to read 0x00 here
      rx_ch= fgetc(fc); 
  if(rx_ch == EOF)break;
  ```
- guest machine engine can hang guest OS window during COM port exchange via pipe (probably by pipe queue overflow);
- etc.

2. 

By tests it was found, that there is the way to read/write client side pipe in half-duplex mode via single `FILE` handler opened for read/write by:

- for mingw pipe win directory is visible as "//./pipe"
- `fopen` pipe in `"rb+"` mode;
- mandatory calls `fseek` (with correct offset) between any read and write pipe operation.

Though the "`fseek` before append" is always mandatory for `"r+"` mode `FILE`, the `fseek` does nothing visible in pipe, but sets internal pipe data into correct state to carry out read and write pipe operation.

3.
example

```
enum{ PR_SYN= 0x16U };

fc= fopen("//./pipe/dos1","rb+"); assert(fc);
fi= fopen("./isw","rb"); assert(fi);
fo= fopen("./osw","ab"); assert(fo);

//
long
    fc_fpos_rx= 0;

for(;;){

    //rx
    assert( !fseek(fc,fc_fpos_rx,SEEK_SET) );

    int
        rx_ch= fgetc(fc); 
    if(rx_ch == EOF)break;

    fc_fpos_rx= ftell(fc); assert( fc_fpos_rx != -1L );

    if(rx_ch != PR_SYN)fputc(rx_ch,fo);

    //tx
    assert( !fseek(fc,0,SEEK_END) );
            
    int
        tx_ch= fi? fgetc(fi): PR_SYN; 
    if(tx_ch == EOF)tx_ch= PR_SYN;

    fputc(tx_ch,fc);
}
```

any suggestions to improve read/write Windows host pipe from client side.

[picture: guest-host pipe file transfer (https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGccG.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGccG.png)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Issues in exploring `<stdio.h>` stream access.

1.
bugfixes

> When we does `fseek()` if the new file pointer points to data that is already in the buffer, nothing need to be done by IO system calls.

by `stdio` convention this is not true, `fseek()` will always reset `FILE*` buffer, only serial 'getc/putc' calls will skip IO system calls.

the convention is taken by `stdio` designers to simplify coherent `FILE*` access by the price of `fseek()` effectivity.

1.2

> "assert(??? != 01L)"

means "-01L"

1.3

> in function `fdup_r()`, "//drop dfcr"

never can "//drop dfcr" due to possible `fdopen` errors (now the function name is changed into `fdup_pipe_r()`)

2.
Some summary info.

conceptually there are two parts of `file handle`: "system" and "per_process"

```
"system" has "per_process" references_list accessed by [process pid]
references_list item {
    long            owner_pid;
    ulong           num_of_the_process_dups;
};
references_list item will be removed if owner_pid terminated or no more `num_of_the_process_dups`  
system handle will be closed if no more references_list "items"

system{
    ulong           lseek_pos;
    references_list per_process[];
    ubits           system_io_restrictions;
}
process{
    long            system_fildes;
    ubits           per_process_io_restrictions;
}
```

2.1
there are several ways to create `file handle` that involves different parts of `file handle`:

```
IO call     system      per_process
open        +           +               check access (chown,chmod) and create new both parts
fork        -           +               dup "per_process" part for new proccess with the same io_restrictions
dup         -           +               dup "per_process" part for current proccess with the same or more strict io_restrictions
dopen       +           +               dup both parts with the same or more strict io_restrictions (is not supported by posix/stdlib)
close       ?           +               close "per_process" part, close "system" part if no more "per_process" refs
```

2.2
we consider `lseek_pos` created as common (in "system part" of `file handle`) in order to simplify "read/write" calls to `file handle` interleaved by different processes without IPC locks usage, from first look there are no ways to get the same behaviour by private `lseek_pos` in "per_process" part.

coherent by process pair { lseek, read/write } requires IPC lock usage in IO access interleaved by different processes

`dup` does for `file handle` the similar as `fork`, but for current process

2.3
"fildes dopen(fildes, io_restriction)" works similar to "FILE* fdopen(fildes, io_restriction)"

the same as `fdopen()` or `dup()`, `dopen()` does not check access (chown,chmod) and uses existed `system_io_restrictions` created by `open()`. io_restriction is `open()` attr "O_RW/O_RO/O_WO".

`dopen` is not supported by posix/stdlib.

`dopen()` works with regular files and pipes.

for pipes `file handle` has no `lseek()` interface (`lseek()` returns `ESPIPE`), so for pipes ordinary `dup()` works very closely to `dopen()`

2.4
the our (not from lib) function `fdup_pipe_r()` is intended for bi_direction "r+" pipes only, to `dup()` from original bi_direction "r+"(O_RW) `FILE*` stream (created by `open()`/`fopen()`) new separated uni_direction "r"(O_RO) `FILE*` stream, in order to use:

- "r+" `FILE*` stream to uni_direction any buffered, pipe only write
- "r" `FILE*` stream to uni_direction any buffered, pipe only read

the function `fdup_pipe_r()` allows us to access guest UART 8250 port from host machine for virtualbox

3.
stdio `FILE*` dups

bi_direction "r+" streams

```
    for bi_direction "r+" `FILE*` access, "pipe" is NOT base interface for any "regular file",  
    for interleaved r/w access in code is intended for "pipe" can not subst any "regular file",  
    the interleaving r/w for "regular file" requires `fseek()/ftell()`  

    for bi_direction "r+" `FILE*` access, "pipe" can not be buffered,  
    it is required to call `setvbuf(_IONBF)` for the "pipe",  
    the interleaving r/w for the "pipe" requires `push_back()` input `FILE*` buffer  

    for bi_direction "r+" `FILE*` access, "pipe" should be splitted by `fdup_pipe_r()`  
    into two separated uni_direction "r"/"w" `FILE*` access  
    to improve interleaved r/w access in code is intended for "pipe"
```

uni_direction "r"/"w" streams

```
    for uni_direction "r"/"w" `FILE*` access, "pipe" IS base interface for SOME "regular file",  
    for uni_direction r/w access in code is intended for "pipe" can subst the "regular file",  
    in which the data is placed in real one-by-one as pipes does  

    so "pipe" interface should be "defined up to complete" by two fake calls:  
        `rewind()` the same as `fseek(0,SEEK_SET)`
        `append()` the same as `fseek(0,SEEK_END)`

    for uni_direction "r"/"w" `FILE*` access (including "r+" pipes splitted by `fdup_pipe_r()`)  
    "pipe" can be buffered by any `_IO?BF` type (by `setvbuf()` call)  

    so "r+" pipes splitted by `fdup_pipe_r()` in the two uni_direction "r"/"w" derived pipes  
    povide any buffered interleaved r/w access in code is intended for "pipe"  
    (by the two uni_direction "r"/"w" derived pipes working together)
```

it is prohibited to create code is intended for "pipe" in uni_direction "r"/"w" `FILE*` access, in which can subst any (without one-by-one placed data) "regular file" by fake `fseek(rand(),SEEK_SET)` calls in the code

```
    if code needs `fseek(rand(),SEEK_SET)` calls, the code is not intended for pipes,  
    the code follows "regular file" interface (by `fseek()` requests),  
    but "regular file" is not base interface for "pipe".  
    
    attempt to subst "pipe" instead of "regular file" interface violates "type checking"
```

4. 

The next improved version of initial example
example4

```
    //
    FILE
        //return "r" mode dupped fr from original "r+"("w") mode fw
        *fdup_pipe_r(
            FILE *const fw
            ){
        int
            dfw, dfr;

        //assume "fileno" returns the same "fildes" value that is stored in the FILE*
        //("fileno" does not make "dup")
        dfw= fileno(fw); assert(dfw != -01L);
        dfr= dup(dfw); assert(dfr != -01L);  
    
        //fr
        FILE
            *fr;

        fr= fdopen(dfr, "rb"); if(!fr)close(dfr);

        return fr;
        //drop dfw, dfr values
    }
    
    //
    {
    enum{ PR_SYN= 0x16U };

    //pipe
    //open pipe in "r+"("w") mode fcw
    fcw= fopen("//./pipe/dos1","rb+"); assert(fcw);
    //return "r" mode dupped fcr from original "r+"("w") mode fcw
    fcr= fdup_pipe_r(fcw); assert(fcr);

    //unbuffered pipe is always required for our AUX port protocol "per char" exchange 
    //but for splitted pipes any buffering type "_IO?BF" could be set
    assert( !setvbuf(fcr, 0, _IONBF, 0) );
    assert( !setvbuf(fcw, 0, _IONBF, 0) );

    //"r+" pipe in interleaved r/w access never allows subst regular file instead of pipe 
    //("rewind()/append()" calls can not help)
    //assert( !fseek(fcr,0,SEEK_SET) );
    //assert( !fseek(fcw,0,SEEK_END) );

    //our AUX port protocol local files
    fi= fopen("./isw","rb"); assert(fi);
    //"a"(create if not exist) + reopen to "r+" + append() 
    fo= fopen("./osw","ab+"); assert(fo); fclose(fo);
    fo= fopen("./osw","rb+"); assert(fo); assert( !fseek(fo,0,SEEK_END) );
    
    //our AUX port protocol exchange loop
    //terminates by ctrl+C
    for(;;){

        //rx
        int
            rx_ch= fgetc(fcr); 
        //"assert( feof(fcr) )" throw error if fgetc(fcr) returned EOF but !feof(fcr) (but better check errno)
        //otherwise endless loop with intention
        if(rx_ch == EOF){ assert( feof(fcr) ); break; } 

        if(rx_ch != PR_SYN)assert( fputc(rx_ch,fo) != EOF );

        //tx
        int
            tx_ch= fi? fgetc(fi): PR_SYN; 
        //"assert( feof(fi) )" throw error if fgetc(fi) returned EOF but !feof(fi) (but better check errno)
        //otherwise endless loop with intention
        if(tx_ch == EOF){ assert( feof(fi) ); tx_ch= PR_SYN; }

        assert( fputc(tx_ch,fcw) != EOF );
    }}
```

Now the example looks better. guest UART 8250 port will be accessed by simple stdio read/write.

Answer (score -1):

Let's continue to explore `<stdio.h>` stream access.

1. 

The original program did not work better because only a few errors returned by system calls was checked by `assert()` in the program.

If we check more returns we got more error messages, we got error messages on every wrong `fputc/fgetc`, that means `stdio` knows about the errors, but only we do not.

```
    int
        //fgetc emits pipe error if there was no fseek
        rx_ch= fgetc(fc); 
    if(rx_ch == EOF){ assert( feof(fc) ); break; } 
    ...

    //fputc emits pipe error if there was no fseek
    assert( fputc(tx_ch,fc) != EOF ); 
    ...
```

The improved version of initial example, 
example2

```
enum{ PR_SYN= 0x16U };

fc= fopen("//./pipe/dos1","rb+"); assert(fc);
//unbuffered is always required for selected AUX port protocol "per char" exchange 
assert( !setvbuf(fc, 0, _IONBF, 0) );

fi= fopen("./isw","rb"); assert(fi);
fo= fopen("./osw","ab"); assert(fo);

//
for(;;){

    //rx
    assert( !fseek(fc,0,SEEK_SET) );

    int
        rx_ch= fgetc(fc); 
    if(rx_ch == EOF){ assert( feof(fc) ); break; } 

    if(rx_ch != PR_SYN)assert( fputc(rx_ch,fo) != EOF );

    //tx
    assert( !fseek(fc,0,SEEK_END) );
            
    int
        tx_ch= fi? fgetc(fi): PR_SYN; 
    if(tx_ch == EOF){ assert( feof(fi) ); tx_ch= PR_SYN; }

    assert( fputc(tx_ch,fc) != EOF );
}
```

We could collect the error messages by more `asserts`, but the messages could not help us to understand "what the error is", because when we tried to access `//./pipe/*` from client side we did assume:

- we must not `fseek()` on pipes (will should always get `ESPIPE` error on every `fseek()`);
- we can not violate OS quotas for number of pipe client side opened handlers (virtualbox pipe server side declares the quotas).

But in real `<stdio.h>` life, we not only "can", we "must", we should do assume:

- we must always DO `fseek()` on pipes when interleave read/write requests (otherwise will always get `fputc/fgetc` error);
- we can violate OS quotas for "number of pipe client side opened handlers" by `dup()` to create "rb"+"ab" separated access handlers pair;
- we must know `dup()` can not "elevate up" RW access of handler created by `open()` (`dup()` can only more restrict the existing RW access created by `open()`).

It is ridiculous, the real `<stdio.h>` conditions are strictly opposit to our expectations, and we must find why.

1.1 
The OS quotas means we can not do like this

```
fcr= fopen("//./pipe/dos1", "rb"); assert(fcr);
fcw= fopen("//./pipe/dos1", "ab"); assert(fcw); //fcw always error
```

Due to the OS quotas we must use "r+" mode to r/w by one bi-directional handler

```
fc= fopen("//./pipe/dos1", "rb+"); assert(fc);
```

As we know, windows has no posix "named FIFOs", means windows kernel does not provide "standard pipe server side" to any number of pipe clients, who has permissions defined by the file system `chmod`/`chown` attrs to connect pipe.

In our case virtualbox provides own access rules of own pipe server side for "//./pipe/dos1" and the 'standard rules' for windows is 'single client only'.

1.2 
One user told us abstract answer: "dup this to anything", so we can write a code to create two separated single_direction streams `fcr`/`fcw`.

The splitted `fcr`/`fcw` streams have no "r+" read/write interleave problems of original bi-directional fc stream.

Mode "a"/"w" is often not the same we need from "w" direction, so we use "r+" as "w" direction and to avoid r/w interleave problems just does not read from "r+".

```
{
//here regular job for 'rb+' access 

//splitted FILE can be buffered 
//this is program responsibility to undestand the r/w buffers are shared or separated 
//and provide coherence of multiple r/w shared buffers
//assert( !setvbuf(fc, 0, _IONBF, 0) );

//must be created in 'r+' access (O_RDWR) 
//the original "rb+" will be used for "w" direction (O_WRONLY)
//dup() also can not "elevate up" RW attr, can not create "w" direction (O_WRONLY) from "r" direction (O_RDONLY)
fcw= fopen("//./pipe/dos1", "rb+"); assert(fcw);

//here function to do the FILE split regular job for 'rb+' access 
{
int
    dfcw, dfcr;

dfcw= fileno(fcw); assert(dfcw != 01L);
dfcr= dup(dfcw); assert(dfcr != 01L);  

fcr= fdopen(dfcr, "rb"); assert(fcr);

//drop dfc, dfcr values
}

//we can declare function 
//to do the FILE split regular job for 'rb+' access 
FILE
    //return "r" mode dupped fcr from original "r+"("w") mode fcw
    *fdup_r(FILE *const fcw);
}
```

1.3 
The next improved version of initial example 
example3

```
//
FILE
    //return "r" mode dupped fcr from original "r+"("w") mode fcw
    *fdup_r(
        FILE *const fcw
        ){
    int
        dfcw, dfcr;

    dfcw= fileno(fcw); assert(dfcw != 01L);
    dfcr= dup(dfcw); assert(dfcr != 01L);  

    //fcr
    return fdopen(dfcr, "rb");
    //drop dfc, dfcr values
}

//
{
enum{ PR_SYN= 0x16U };

//pipe
//open pipe in "r+"("w") mode fcw
fcw= fopen("//./pipe/dos1","rb+"); assert(fcw);
//return "r" mode dupped fcr from original "r+"("w") mode fcw
fcr= fdup_r(fcw); assert(fcr);

//unbuffered pipe is always required for our AUX port protocol "per char" exchange 
assert( !setvbuf(fcr, 0, _IONBF, 0) );
assert( !setvbuf(fcw, 0, _IONBF, 0) );

//allow subst regular file instead of pipe 
assert( !fseek(fcr,0,SEEK_SET) );
assert( !fseek(fcw,0,SEEK_END) );

//local files
fi= fopen("./isw","rb"); assert(fi);
//append + reopen to r+
fo= fopen("./osw","ab+"); assert(fo); fclose(fo);
fo= fopen("./osw","rb+"); assert(fo); assert( !fseek(fo,0,SEEK_END) );

//exchange loop
for(;;){

    //rx
    int
        rx_ch= fgetc(fcr); 
    if(rx_ch == EOF){ assert( feof(fcr) ); break; } 

    if(rx_ch != PR_SYN)assert( fputc(rx_ch,fo) != EOF );

    //tx
    int
        tx_ch= fi? fgetc(fi): PR_SYN; 
    if(tx_ch == EOF){ assert( feof(fi) ); tx_ch= PR_SYN; }

    assert( fputc(tx_ch,fcw) != EOF );
}}
```

Now the example looks better, there are no more:

- fseek on pipe;
- fseek on every write to local file;
- fseek two times/per loop pass on every r/w interleave for pipe.

2. 

There are some questions about `<stdlib.h>`.

About `dup()` behaviour.

Due to the guess about the `dup()` behaviour we can explain why:

- `dup()` can violate OS quotas for number of opened handlers;
- `dup()` can not "elevate up" RW access of `system_handler` created by `open()` (`dup()` can only more restrict the existing RW access created by `open()`).

It looks like process handler is abstract structure `{ system_handler data, local_handler data}`.

`open()` creates both members in the abstract structure, but `dup` can change only `local_handler` field, copying the same `system_handler` field to new handler.

That means that from OS point of view, all `duped` handlers does the same access via the same `system_handler`, as if we several times called `fread()` for the same `system_handler` directly.

3. 

Why we must not do `fseek()` on pipes?

Unrelated to `stdio` rules, we can not `fseek()` on devices which are incapable of seeking because there are no file pointer here, the devices are represented as pair `{input_port, output_port}`:

- there is no position of data inside each IO direction (not exist "input position" or "output position");
- there is no position of data between different IO directions ("input_port position" is not less, more or equal to "output position");

there are many devices that follow the restrictions.

And the "posix prog man" claims

- "for `fseek()` the value of the file offset on devices which are incapable of seeking is undefined".

that means `stdio` is ignoring `{offset,whence}` parameters of `fseek()` call on `FILE` which are incapable of seeking and `fseek(fc, rand(), rand())` also will work in our example2 instead of `assert( !fseek(fc,0,0) )`.

The "posix prog man" claims

- "the behavior of `fseek()` on devices which are incapable of seeking is implementation-defined"

that means we must not call `fseek()` on devices which are incapable of seeking, `fseek()` must be used for directly purpose only, in order to set file pointer and not for any other jobs.

3.1 
The question is ability to subst regular file instead of trivial pipe in the same program.

In order to work in program with regular file as if the file is a trivial pipe, we can restrict in the program `fseek()` usage to cases:

- sequential read file starting from begin of file `fseek(fi,0,SEEK_SET)`;
- sequential write file by append after end of file `fseek(fo,0,SEEK_END)`.

That means pipe should "defines up to complete" the prohibited `fseek()` by the two allowed `fseek()` calls with parameters '(0,SEEK_SET)/(0,SEEK_END)'.

The `fseek()` parameters have no sense for pipe but provide compatibility of pipe with regular file (SEEK_SET refer to read pipe, SEEK_END refer to write pipe).

sure, the purpose of `stdio` is to avoid us from dig the stream details and guess stream attr combinations, i have never looked so closely before.

3.2 
We can imagine `stdio` based program, that does random access to regular file by `fseek(offset)`, `fread(size)`/`fwrite(size)`. Later we decided to feed the program by pipe instead of regular file, using external software created "gathered" pipe with "chuncks" of the same (offset,size).

In the case we need `stdio` behaviour is ignoring `{offset, whence}` parameters of `fseek()` call on pipe.

But in real the similar "gathered" pipe is just improper use of pipe, the programming technic produces unreliable code and leads to runtime errors, just believe that runtime errors is one of the most unpleasure thing you want to get.

Improper in comparison with "mapping regular file to pipe" that is implemented by only two special cases of `fseek(fi,0,SEEK_SET)`/`fseek(fi,0,SEEK_END)` calls allowed for pipe.

4. 

why we need `fseek()` for r/w interleave in buffered "r+" mode?

FILE provides single buffer to IO and read/write data from downlayer handler by "chunks" into the buffer (reducing IO system calls).

When we does `fseek()` if the new file pointer points to data that is already in the buffer, nothing need to be done by IO system calls.

but when in "r+" mode we change IO direction (read->write or write->read) we need flush dirty write buffer and drop (invalidate by LRU rules) obsolete read buffer.

But flush only is not enough, most time pointer in `FILE` and pointer in downlayer handler are not the same, we need `fseek` to change IO direction. 
consider

```
//read
fseek(0,0)
    seek (0,0)
    //here FILE and downlayer handler both points to 0
fgetc
    //read into buf 
    read(0,4K)
    //here FILE points to buf[1]
    //and downlayer handler points to file[4K]
    //char was returned from FILE buf[0]

//write
fseek(100,0)
    //drop input buf
    //here previous input [1..4K) will be dropped 
        
        //!HERE "on devices which are incapable of seeking" we can not fseek
        //all dropped data will be lost, we can not "push back" the read data into pipe
        //input stream data will be damaged just because we try write after read
        
        //"on devices which are incapable of seeking" just split pipe by `fdup_r()`
        //or disable buffering by `setvbuf(FILE, 0, _IONBF, 0)`

    //seek new write pos 100
    seek (100,0)
    //here FILE and downlayer handler both points to 100
fputc
    //write into buf 
    //here FILE points to 101
    //char was placed into FILE buf[0]

    //here downlayer handler points to 100
    //write(100,1) was not called
```

"on devices which are incapable of seeking" in buffered "r+" mode just split pipe by `fdup_r()` or disable buffering by `setvbuf(FILE, 0, _IONBF, 0)`.

5. 

As result.

Once time earlier we have claimed "posix provides reliable way to access streams", but now we see this was not really true, there are some issues here.

And i have never seen the same info about `dup()` and 'r+' mode in "prog references".